# Rmi for centralized database systems?

Tags: java, database, rmi

I have to develop a java application with a centralized database. Is RMI suitable for it or should i use some other method.

Comment: Yes and no. What are your requirements? How are clients likely to connect to the system? Are there only Java clients that need to connect?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The clients that would be using will have a java application to query and the number of clients is very small.But the database should be concurrent.

Comment: RMI will work, but it brings with it some headaches. The good is, you get to deal with Java objects, which if written correctly, bring along the business logic required to manage them, this means you get validation of the objects in (virtually) real time, without the need to query the server independently. The down side is you lock yourself into technological base which will limit the future of your application (only Java applications can talk with RMI)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The limitation is not an issue.Is there a way other than RMI to develop such an application on Java.

Comment: Lots. You could use J2EE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use Java EE. The Java EE application will have the server side logic and manages access to the database via EJBs.

You can use either remote EJBs, which are based on RMI, but usually only work in a LAN. Or you can create SOAP or RESTful webservices using the easy to use JAX-WS and JAX-RS annotations.

You can find the Java EE tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/

You will need an application server. The reference implementation is GlassFish: http://glassfish.java.net/

The easiest way to get started is to download a NetBeans version with a bundled GlassFish: http://netbeans.org/downloads/

Then just create a WAR project.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer by Puce, but you can also consider a different kind of application server (without EJBs or RMI) such as [Vaadin](http://www.vaadin.com/) (Java-based) or [Real Studio Web Edition](http://www.realsoftware.com/web/) (not Java-based). The user interacts with a web browser on the client-side while your app's business logic executes on the server and connects to the database server.